# Knockoutjs id reference to object

Tags: knockout.js, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

Simple Question I think.

I got a Kendo Multiselect which is bound to an array of objects (contentLangs).

From backend I get an array of ints (`AvailableLanguages`).

Now my problem is how to bind the values correctly.

Do I need a computed or something like this?

Thanks in advance!

```
<select data-bind="kendoMultiSelect: {
    data: contentLangs ,
    dataTextField: 'Name',
    dataValueField: 'ID',
    value: AvailableLanguages,
    index: 0,
    height: '500'
}"></select>

AvailableLanguages: [0,1]

var contentLangs = [
    { Name: "Deutsch", ID: "DE", Cls: "language-flag flag-de" },
    { Name: "Englisch", ID: "EN", Cls: "language-flag flag-en" },
    { Name: "Italienisch", ID: "IT", Cls: "language-flag flag-it" }
]
```

Comment: What's the availableLanguages meant to be? Is contentLangs supposed to be in the dropdown?

Comment: sorry @WayneEllery, contentLangs is the data/dataSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to create your view model like so:

```
var viewModel = {
  availableLanguages: ko.observable([0,1]),
  contentLangs: [
    { Name: "Deutsch", ID: "DE", Cls: "language-flag flag-de" },
    { Name: "Englisch", ID: "EN", Cls: "language-flag flag-en" },
    { Name: "Italienisch", ID: "IT", Cls: "language-flag flag-it" }
  ]
};
```

`contentLangs` doesn't need to be an observableArray unless it changes. `availableLanguages` needs to be an observable because we need to update the viewModel when the selection changes.

Then you can bind the viewModel to the view using:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And the view would be:

```
<select data-bind="kendoMultiSelect: {
    data: contentLangs,
    dataTextField: 'Name',
    dataValueField: 'ID',
    value: availableLanguages,
    index: 0,
    height: '500'
}"></select>
```

Comment: ok thanks, I think I was a bit unclear. But your answer give me right impulse. I added a real Id to contentLangs - now it works. :-)